# why is my relativeLayout doesn't appear below its sibling linearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@color/blue_bg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.my.view.text.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/whyResgisterHeaderText"
            style="@style/textOnBg"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="WHY REGISTER?"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.my.view.text.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/whyResgisterBodyText"
            style="@style/textOnBg"
            android:text="Help us keep your account safe"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/signup_illu_why" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gotItButton"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
                android:padding="0dp" />

            <com.my.view.text.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/gotItText"
                style="@style/textOnBg"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Got it"
                android:textColor="#00bcfe"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#70a5b3" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <com.my.view.text.MyTextView
                style="@style/textOnBg"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/skipIcon"
                android:text="Skip"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/skipIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/signup_skip_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want my screen to look like:

[image]

but it looks like:

[image]

1) why cannot I see the fotter relativeLayout (with the "skip")

2) how can I center the `gotItText` textView? why isn't it center with current properties?

Comment: In my IDE it works as you want, if I change the custom TextView to default TextView and remove all styles.

Comment: Try to go through the xml, and check the layout height attribute of RelativeLayout, that is "wrap_content" and it's child LinearLayout(which include "skip" has alignParent). this is contradictory in itself. Set the attribute of top RelativeLayout as "match_parent". Let me know if that works!!

Answer (score 0):

Because your root layout is a RelativeLayout.

You should declare an ID for the first LinearLayout, and then use layout_below property on the second one. Remember, their positions are relatives so if you don't specify the location of the second Linear, it will be paint over the first one.

If you want to get one linear below the other automatically use a LinearLayout as main root.

Answer (score 0):

Edited you code, replaced the custom EditTexts, and removed the styles, set new heights to the layout and it seems to be working as you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/whyResgisterHeaderText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="WHY REGISTER?"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/whyResgisterBodyText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Help us keep your account safe"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gotItButton"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gotItText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Got it"
                android:textColor="#00bcfe"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#70a5b3" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/skipIcon"
                android:text="Skip"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/skipIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```